# How to add a ContentBySearchWebPart programmatically?

Tags: web-part

How to add a ContentBySearchWebPart programmatically to a webpartmanager?

The class ContentBySearchWebPart does not exists!

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using ? That webpart is only available in Enterprise.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You need to add this reference dll : using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll. It is included in the 15 hives folder. This is also needed for the other search webparts like refinementswebpart.